# Can I disable my GPU for enegry saving?

Tags: gpu

I have two graphic card but both of them can't remove because my computer is Hp All In One and I want to disable both of them to run my new GPU. So does in theoretically is this possible ?

Comment: This seems non-nonsensical - if you have 2 graphics card and want to add a new one, how do you intend to do that if both the existing ones are not removable (are you sure you meant existing graphic cards and not multiple ports for built in GPU built onto motherboard - in which case you may be able to turn it off in BIOS when the new GPU card is detected)

Comment: I have two m.2 slot and m.2 to pcie adapter which mean I can have 3 gpu @davidgo

Comment: So please stop downvote

Comment: I did not down voted you (and  I always leave reasons if I down voted someone). BTW your response does not make sense - if they are in m.2 slots surely they can be removed? Also,  using m.2 to power graphics is not generally a great idea - due to the high risk of damaging something because most graphics cards will use more then 10 watts of power and are bottlenecked by m.2 pciI bandwidth.

Comment: No i saying that my new gpu is in m.2 slot because the other two that all of the space

Comment: Care to put your last sentence in English and explain why you can't remove an existing card from its slot? Also, what model GPU are you trying to add? No offense but there is something not right about this whole question.

Comment: My model is zotac geforce gtx 1050 and i can remove it because 1 of them is intergrated and others is dedicated but soldered and it very bad at playing game because this pc is like a workstation

Comment: The document here https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04874664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do almost certainly won't work - and if it will, its going to die pretty quickly.

The core problem you have is that a Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 [requires at least 75 watts](https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/zotac-geforce-gtx-1050-mini#spec) (depending on exact variant) and the recommended PSU is at least 300 watts.

This causes at least 2 problems

- Your PSU is only rated at 150 watts, and you are most likely going to come very close, or probably exceed this - your CPU alone takes 30 watts, in addition to motherboard, memory and disk requirements.
- An  M.2 card can only provide 10 watts - and most riser cards only will only allow you to push 10 watts (some will do 25 watts with plug in power).  This will be insufficient to drive the graphics card.

Even if you can make this work, by the time you have factored in the slowdowns due to the m.2 to PCI-E bottleneck you will probably have a GPU which performs about the same or slower then the built in one.

Comment: I heaelrd on the internet that people can make graphic card work on m.2 slot

Comment: Yes, because everything everyone says on the Internet is correct. (It is possible, but you need to hack stuff to add additional power into the GPU and I don't think your GPU is designed for this - and the built in PUS definitely isnt). Have a read of https://hardforum.com/threads/can-you-run-a-gpu-off-a-m-2-slot.1900885/ )

Comment: Can u help me with how to remove soldered gpu or intergrated ?

Comment: Sorry, no. This requires expertise in a different field which I do not have, and is very risky without the correct tools and knowhow.  Even doing this will not fix your problem that your new GPU is to power hungry for your PSU - you would be better off selling the system and buying a replacement which is not all-in-one. Further, removing the built in card could cause Bo's/boot problems which I would not want to be responsible for.

Comment: Also, let's pretend you can put in another card and disable the onboard one - have you considered how you would connect it to the internal screen? (You might be able to loop it back in through HDMI port, but that would seem messy and problematic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73463/discussion-between-alphabeta-and-davidgo).